# Сделать большие буквы маленькими toLowerCase на JS

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть такой код JS. Использую его в Google Scripts:

```
function lowercase (event) {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('My_ID');
  var editedCell = source.getActiveCell();
  var tableRange = "A2:E900";
  var columnTo = 2;

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnTo){
    var range = source.getRange(tableRange);
    range.toLowerCase( {
      column: columnTo
    });
  }

}
```

Хочу, чтобы во втором столбце в гугл таблице все прописные буквы становились строчными.

Этот код не вызывает ошибок, но не работает, ничего в таблице не меняется.

Где ошибка в коде? Подскажите, пожалуйста...

Comment: что делает `source.getRange(tableRange)`?

Comment: @Дмытрык я только начинающий в js, плохо понимаю этот язык, этот код взял из похожего. Как я понимаю, эта строка задаёт диапазон.

Comment: не вижу у [`range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#methods) метода `toLowerCase`. Ошибок может не быть если код не заходит внутрь `if`, То есть `editedCell.getColumn()` не равен `2`